# how can i fix the Indentation Error in using pandas and jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

Below is the code which i have tried and also i have posted the error what i got. Please help

```
 X_all.HM1 = X_all.HM1.astype('str')
 X_all.HM2 = X_all.HM2.astype('str')
                X_all.HM3 = X_all.HM3.astype('str')
                X_all.AM1 = X_all.AM1.astype('str')
                X_all.AM2 = X_all.AM2.astype('str')
                X_all.AM3 = X_all.AM3.astype('str')

def preprocess_features(X):
                    output = pd.DataFrame(index = X.index)

                    for col, col_df in X.iteritems():

             if col_df.dtype == object:
                        col_df = pd.get_dummies(col_df, prefix = col)

                       output = output.join(col_df)

                         return output

            X_all = preprocess_features(X_all)
            print "Processed feature columns ({} total features):\n{}".format(len(X_all.columns), list(X_all.columns))

            print "\nFeature values:"
            display (X_all)`
```

This is the error i have got 
            File "", line 37
                if col_df.dtype == object:

Comment: Try wrapping object in quotation marks.

Comment: Python is indentation sensitive. Could you update the code in the question to match your code exactly (especially the whitespace)?

Comment: Hi i tried that and now im getting other error  which is this :::: def preprocess_features(X):
            output = pd.DataFrame(index = X.index)
                for col, col_df in X.iteritems():
             
           
    
  File "<ipython-input-91-43ecf6dbb517>", line 22
    def preprocess_features(X):
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: File "<ipython-input-107-9bf61c654c95>", line 15
    print "Processed feature columns ({} total features):\n{}".format(len(X_all.columns), list(X_all.columns))
                                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax  this is the recent error after indentation i have got now